# Compare two string using JavaScript and substitute an ampersand for the word and

Tags: javascript, regex, vue.js

I need to compare two string that come from two different data sources.  In one system they could put the word **and** and in the other it could be **&** or it could be the other way around or they could be the same.

Currently I'm using

```
            if (thisAffiliation.search(new RegExp(department, "i")) > 0) {   
            validatedDepartment = true
            }

            if (thisAffiliation.search(new RegExp(department.replace('and','&'), "i")) > 0) {   
            validatedDepartment = true
             }

            if (thisAffiliation.search(new RegExp(department.replace('&','and'), "i")) > 0) {   
            validatedDepartment = true
             }
```

Is there a way that I can combine the three if statements into one?

Added information:

I need to have validatedDepartment  = true if:

```
        Smith and Jones   =   Smith & Jones
        Smith and Jones   =   Smith and Jones
```

or if it is

```
        Smith & Jones    =  Smith & Jones
        Smith & Jones    = Smith and Jones
```

I have no control where the and or & show up

Comment: Logical OR: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR

Comment: ...or you could create a single regex to handle all three searches.

Comment: this works  if (thisAffiliation.search(new RegExp(department, "i")) > 0  || thisAffiliation.search(new RegExp(department.replace('and','&'), "i")) > 0 || thisAffiliation.search(new RegExp(department.replace('&','and'), "i")) > 0) {   
                  validatedDepartment = true
                 } but for readabilty I think the original is better

Comment: And I don't know how to use RegEx so it does not think it a loop- of changing & for and and back again.  And if the person who down graded the question could produce an intelligent solution I would appreciate it

Comment: So you want to accept when one is a substring of the other, but not equal?

Comment: I added some additional information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not have to create a regular expression from the input string for this (unless the source value *represents* a regular expression).

To make no difference between "and" and "&", just make the conversion in one direction, in *both* strings, and just do it always. Use a function to apply the same logic to both strings:

```
const clean = (s) => s.replace(/&/g, "and").toLowerCase();

if (clean(thisAffiliation) === clean(department)) {   
    validatedDepartment = true;
}
```

If there are no other conditions for influencing the value of `validatedDepartment`, then you can just assign the boolean condition:

```
let validatedDepartment = clean(thisAffiliation) === clean(department);
```

Comment: Perfect-- exactly what I was looking for.  Making the conversion to both to the same direction is what I was hoping for but could not picture.   Thank you